# Linear combinations of vector $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ and combinations with repetitions $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There are

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1} \tag{1}$$

nonnegative vectors $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$  such that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_r=n, \ \  \ \ \ \ x_i \ge 0, \ \ \ 1 \le i \le r$

Then the number of selections of repetition of $r$ objects from $n$ types of objects is  $$\binom{n+r-1}{r} \tag{2}$$

Besides $(1)$ differing from $(2)$ by a factor of $\frac{n}{r}$, how are these two related (in a meaningful way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are related by interchange of the roles of $n$ and $r$, which is more evident if you write the first binomial coefficient $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ as $\binom{n+r-1}n$. So one should really compare (and equate) that number to the number of ways to select with repetitions $n$ objects from $r$ types available (in sufficient quantity). Now the correspondence is clear: $x_i$ counts the selected of objects of type$~i$.

Added in order reply to some comments: it is hard to answer a question that asks about relating two counting problems that have *different* binomial coefficients as answers; my answer is that the binomial coefficient expressions can be made equal by interchanging the roles of $n$ and $r$ between one and the other. (It is like asking the relation between $(x+1)^2(y-4)$ and $(x-4)(y+1)^2$; the best answer is that these are unrelated as polynomials in $x,y$, yet one can be transformed into the other by interchanging the names $x$ and $y$.)

Now maybe a deeper question is why in selction-with-repetition problems there is this strange shifted symmetry: the number of ways to select with repetition $n$ objects from $r$ types is equal to the number of ways to select with repetition $r-1$ objects from $n+1$ types. In terms of "[multiset numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_number#Counting_multisets)" notation, the relation $$\left(\!\!\binom rn\!\!\right)=\left(\!\!\binom{n+1}{r-1}\!\!\right).$$ The best explanation for this I have to offer is to represent performing such a selection by choosing a lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(n,r-1)$ (using Cartesian coordinates): each horizontal step selects an object of type given by the current height (so types are numbered from $0$ to $r-1$), while vertical steps mean passing to the next type without selecting anything. The obvious symmetry now is reflecting the path in the main diagonal, which operation puts $r-1$ into the role of number of objects to be selected, and $n$ in the role of "one less than the number of types".

Comment: I had this interpretation for $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ in mind already.  That is, $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ counts the number of ways to select $n$ indistinguishable objects from a set of $r$ distinguishable elements (e.g. urns), where each $x_i$ for $1 \le i \le r$ may represent the count of each of the $r$ distinguishable types, and any of the $r$ types may be repeated anywhere from $1 \le x_i \le n$ times. Is this the correspondence you meant?

Comment: Marc, I upvoted, but I am not sure whether your answer is so succinct that I've missed how it answers my question, or it partially answers my question, or it is answers a different question.

Comment: I see now that two different bars-and-stars or $0$s-and-$1$s argument can explain $(1)$ and $(2)$. The argument for $(2)$ has a $0$ for each of the $r$ indistinguishable objects to select from $n$ types. Let a $0$ stand in place for each of the $r$, "divide" them among the $n$ types with $(n-1)$ $1$s. The argument for $(1)$ has $n$ $0$s for the indistinguishable $n$ objects, and $r-1$ $1$s to "divide" them among $r$ types. In either case, the length of the string is $(n+r-1)$